Change background color of parts of the text, possibly containing floats
With tcolorbox, for example, it's possible to change the background color of parts of the text (even from one page to another, thanks to its breakable library). But it relies on boxes that can't contain floats.
Is there a way to change the background color of text parts that may contain floats (these floats, which may be outside the background-colored parts, don't need to be background-colored themselves)?
The input would be an environment containing quite arbitrary content, possibly resulting in text across several pages, and only this text would have to be background-colored.
An example of what I'm after is the following where the myenv environment, instead of coloring the text in cyan, would color the background of the text in cyan.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{myenv}{\color{cyan}}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{myenv}
  \lipsum[2-8]

  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption A}
    \label{A}
  \end{figure}

  \lipsum[7]
\end{myenv}

\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}


What would you input be? How many pages? One could use the bg hook for simple stuff.

@daleif The input could be quite arbitrary, possibly resulting in content across several pages. Do you mean the shipout/background hook?

Yes that hook. I meant would it be an environment that should mark this? Is it only the text, or the entire page? It is just to figure out some baselines. I have no idea on how to solve this, but felt the question needed some clarity.

@daleif I edited the question in order to make it clarified (?)

Could you add an example, with blindtext and 1 or 2 floats, over several pages, indicating intended colors, e.g. via \marginpar? Thank you

@MS-SPO Example added.
